# MaxErrorRetry Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running in a problem with my firebase server (free version).
I dient change a thing in my function but suddenly the error max retry error occurs. It ran well for a long time and now it changed. A function gets called like limitlessly until it crashes and the error message occurs.

My code which is causing the problem

```
func calculateScore(postId: String,  onSuccess: @escaping (Post) -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void){
    let postRef = API.Post.REF_POST.child(postId)

    postRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
        if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

            let likeCount = post["likeCount"] as? Double ?? 0
            var score = post["score"] as? Double ?? 0

            let time = post["creationDate"] as? TimeInterval ?? 0
            let commentCount = post["commentCount"] as? Double ?? 0
            let now = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
            let currentDate = now.subtracting(time)
            let difference = Double(currentDate) / 60

            print("date:", currentDate, "Unterschied in Minuten" ,difference)


             score =  (likeCount * 100) + (commentCount * 50) - (difference * 0.01)
            print("Score ist ", score)

            post["commentCount"] = commentCount as AnyObject?
            post["creationDate"] = time as AnyObject?
            post["score"] = score as AnyObject?
            post["likeCount"] = likeCount as AnyObject?
            currentData.value = post

            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
        return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            onError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        if let dict = snapshot?.value as? [String: Any] {
            let post = Post.transformPost(dict: dict, key: snapshot!.key)
            onSuccess(post)
        }
    }

}
```

Any Idea ? I have looked around a bit and even contacted the support but even that did not help me.
Cheers